# A node class for Graphs (c++)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, nodes

I'm trying to build a class for nodes. However it seems that using the copy construction like I did below generates the error : `error: conversion from 'Node<int>*' to non-scalar type 'Node<int>' requested`

the compiler points to the line `Node<int> child= new Node<int>(*(n.returnChildren()[0]));`

Please note the purpose of my question is learning C++, I know that I can find a better class on the net. Thank you

here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

/* ******************************************************* Node ********************************************************* */

template<class T>
class Node
{
    private:
        T _value;
        vector<Node*> children;

    public:
        Node(T value);
        Node(const Node<T>& node);
        void AddChild(Node<T>* node);
        T getValue() const;
        vector<Node<T>*> returnChildren() const;
        //~Node();
};

template <class T>
Node<T>::Node(T value):_value(value)
{
    children.push_back(NULL);
}

template <class T>
Node<T>::Node(const Node& node):_value(node.getValue()), 
                                children(node.returnChildren())
{
}

template <class T>
void Node<T>::AddChild(Node* node)
{
    if (children[0]=NULL){children.pop_back();};
    children.push_back(node);
}

template <class T>
T Node<T>::getValue() const
{
    return _value;
}

template <class T>
vector<Node<T>*> Node<T>::returnChildren() const
{
    return children;
}
/*
template <class T>
Node<T>::~Node()
{
    for (vector<Node<T>*>::iterator it=children.begin() ; it!=children.end() ; it++)
    {
                    delete (*it);
    }
}*/



int main()
{
    Node<int> n(3);
    Node<int> nn(4);
    n.AddChild(&nn);
    Node<int> child= new Node<int>(*(n.returnChildren()[0]));
}
```

Comment: I maybe helps to mark the position where the compiler error occurs.

Comment: vector<Node*> children; i think you may actualy define the class template for the Node pointer as follows: vector<Node<T>*> children;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is said in the error message. 
`new` returns a pointer to a newly created object, not the object itself.
Use the following line instead:

```
Node<int> *child = new Node<int>(*(n.returnChildren()[0]));
```

And don't forget to `delete child;` after use.

**Update:**
You don't need to `push_back(NULL)`. You better just leave the vector empty and remove the check in `AddChild`.

**Update 2:**
By the way, this is not comparison, but an assignment:

```
if (children[0]=NULL){;;;};
```